# HTML Url Request Parameter

Tags: html, url

I have a local test-page. The URL is:

```
file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/HTML/TEST/URLREST/Test.html
```

I only want to change the URL in

```
file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/HTML/TEST/URLREST/Test.html?id=2
```

or something like that. Just a different URL.

How i can manage that?

I wrote this site in html.

Comment: can you explain ?? by calling www.example.com/test.html?id=2 is the same as www.example.com/test.html only in the first one you send a GET variable named id with a value 2 that the difference

Comment: Yes, it is a test. I am learning html and try to test some things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript>
   window.location.href = 'file:///C:/Users/User/Desktop/HTML/TEST/URLREST/Test.html?id=2';
</script>
```